# Defining and calling function in one step

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, iife

Is there a way in Javascript to define a function and immediately call it, in a way that allows it to be reused?

I know you can do one-off anonymous functions:

```
(function(i) {
    var product = i * i;
    console.log(product);
    // Can't recurse here because there's no (ECMA standard) way for the 
    // function to refer to itself
}(2)); // logs 4
```

Or you can name a function then call it afterwards:

```
function powers(i) {
    var product = i * i;
    console.log(i * i);
    if (product < 1e6) { powers(product) };
}

powers(2); // Logs 4, 16, 256...
```

But is there a cleaner way of defining and calling a function in one go? Sort of like a hybrid of both examples?

Not being able to do this isn't preventing me from doing anything, but it feels like it would be a nice expressive way to write recursive functions or functions that need to be run on `$(document).ready()` but also later when situations change, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I name a javascript function and execute it immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404196/can-i-name-a-javascript-function-and-execute-it-immediately)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can try:

```js
(window.powers = function(i) {
  /*Code here*/
  alert('test : ' + i);
})(2);
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="powers(654)">Click</a>
```

Working link : http://jsfiddle.net/SqBp8/

It gets called on load, and I have added it to an `anchor tag` to change the parameter and `alert`.

Comment: Clever solution! Works without the `window.` as well, but obviously implied globals are evil...

Comment: Just add a `var powers;` before the immediately executing function and you're good to go.

Answer (score 41):

If all you want is access the function within its own body, you can simply specify a name after the `function` keyword:

```
> (function fac (n) {
    return (n === 0 ? 1 : n*fac(n-1));
  })(10)
3628800
```

This is a standard feature (see [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), ed. 5.1, p. 98).

Comment: This is very elegant for what it does.

Answer (score 15):

All the answers here are close to what you want, but have a few problems (adding it to the global scope, not actually calling it, etc). This combines a few examples on this page (although it unfortunately requires you to remember `arguments.callee`):

```
var test = (function() {
  alert('hi');
  return arguments.callee;
})();
```

Later, you can call it:

```
test();
```

Comment: The only problem is that arguments.callee is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) and throws an error on ES5 in strict mode.

Comment: @Tivie But you can name the anonymous function. `var test = (function fn() { alert('hi'); return fn; })();`

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about the return value, you can do this.

```
var powers = function powers(i) {
    var product = i * i;
    console.log(i * i);
    if (product < 1e6) { powers(product) };
    return powers;
}(2);
```