# Immediately invoke function and call in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iife

I'm busy working on an AngularJS application which gets data from an API. However I'm wondering if there's a possibility to directly invoke a function in the scope AND call it normally.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
var self = this;
$scope.refreshData = (function() {
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './test-api/testdata.php'
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            self.apiData = data;
        });
    console.log('Refresh executed');
})();

$interval(function() {
    console.log('Refresh called');
    $scope.refreshData();
}, 60000);
```

This logs:

```
Refresh executed
angular.js:13540 TypeError: $scope.refreshData is not a function
```

I know I can just change it to a normal function and call it with `$scope.refreshData()`, but I was just wondering if there's a method for it in AngularJS.

Comment: its just the same rules for javascript here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.refreshData here is undefined as the value you assigned to it is the value returned by the IIFE. In order for this to work, you should do the following:

```
var self = this;
($scope.refreshData = function() {
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './test-api/testdata.php'
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            self.apiData = data;
        });
    console.log('Refresh executed');
})(); 

$interval(function() {
    $scope.refreshData();
    console.log('Refresh called');
}, 60000);
```

PS: You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404196/can-i-name-a-javascript-function-and-execute-it-immediately).

Comment: Read my last sentence of my question. I know it can be done that way, but I was wondering if I could invoke it directly on load and call it later on (in my example in an interval)

Comment: Yeah I see, works for me too. Never thought about putting the `(` before the `$scope`.