# dragging and sorting is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, drag

When I insert a data through ajax, I have used

```
$( "#example_wrap" ).load(window.location.href + " #example" );
```

to reload a div, but after this has done, my dragging and sorting the list is not working, so I just used

```
        sort_table;
        $('#example tbody').sortable('destroy');        
        $('#example tbody').unbind();
        sort_table;
```

sorting functions are assigned to the variable `sort_table`

```
sort_table =
$( "#example tbody" ).sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var self = $(this)[0];
        var tr = $(self).find('tr');

        topnews_a = [];
        var order = 1;
        $(tr).each(function(){
            var content_id = parseInt( $(this).attr('content_id') );
            var order_id = order;

            topnews_a.push({
                content_id: content_id,
                order_id: order_id,
            });
            order++;
        });
        var topnews_obj = JSON.stringify(topnews_a);
        var data_a = {
            topnews: topnews_obj
        }



        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: base_url+"topnews/do_order",
            data: data_a,
            beforeSend:function(){
                //$('.clearClassBlock').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">Select A Section.</div>');
            },
            complete:function(){

            },
            success:function(x){
                alert('Order Changed Successfully');
            },
            error:function(x){

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If `sort_table` is a function you need to invoke it: `sort_table();`

Comment: sort_table variable code is added with the question, and im not created a function withing the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First thing first:** As per MDN unnamed functions (a function assigned to a variable) should be attached to event for callback.

After

> sorting functions are assigned to the variable sort_table

this is not sorting functions once you assign this to a variable, it is now function expression as definition is without function keyword as first statement.

When you call the variable without `()` then it will return the expression definition as your asking for the value of the variable (not invoking a function) .

So you need to invoke your function expression.
`sort_table();` the `sort_table` should be declared before you invoke it.

Further you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404196/can-i-name-a-javascript-function-and-execute-it-immediately) for  how to name a javascript function and execute it immediately?

Comment: But whenever tries this also, not working... after refreshing query is running, sorting function will not work.

Comment: have you referred the url from answer and tried with `sort_table = function() {
$( "#example tbody" ).sortable( ........ };`