# Why can't I store the result of a promise (or a chained promise) in a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch

This is a silly question but can you explain what is wrong with this code?
Why can't I perform this?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const fetchProm = (() => {
    return fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github');
}).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then((json) => {
    console.log(json)
});
```

Comment: The json u r getting in the end can be assigned to a variable, so that u can use it later. To read more about promises https://mdn.io/promise

Comment: Instead of console.log you should return the JSON, then it would have it’s value... (if you call the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Declaring a function is not the same as calling one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404196/can-i-name-a-javascript-function-and-execute-it-immediately)

You are not calling the function that returns the promise, just declaring it. You'll need to add an additional set of parentheses before the first `.then()` in order to actually *call* the function:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const fetchProm = (() => {
    return fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github');
})().then((response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then((json) => {
    console.log(json)
});
```

If you want to call *everything* at a later time, you need to place the whole thing in its own function where the promises get handled in an isolated scope:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const fetchProm = () => {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
};

fetchProm();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! 
I guess there is no way to have a chain of promises declared under a single variable and I have to break them down, is this correct?

Comment: Sorry to keep doing this, I've actually just added a little bit that puts the whole thing in a singular function!

Comment: Why would you not just do `fetch(...).then(...)` here? What does the wrapping function add?

Comment: I assumed all that was wanted was an isolated context. I believe the initial misunderstanding was @νόουμπάντυ thinking that calling the `fetchProm()` method would _automatically_ call all subsequent chained promises.