# Scope issue inside a custom object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scope

I think I am having a scope visibility issue I can't figure out exactly: when I log the variable `displayatonce` I get back the right result, but as I try to use the buttons I get nothing in return. I have also tried to log `this.navbuttons` but all I get is an empty set... I really don't get what's wrong with this code.

```
<!-- html code -->
<div id="nav">
<a href="#" data-dir="prev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" data-dir="next">Next</a>
</div>

/* Js Script with jQuery */
(function() {

var NewsNavigator = {

    init: function(config) {
        this.navbuttons = config.navbuttons;
        this.displayatonce = config.displayatonce;
        this.counter = 0;
        this.showNews();
        this.enableNav();

    },

    showNews: function() {
        console.log(this.displayatonce);
    },

    enableNav: function() {
                    console.log(this.navbuttons);
        this.navbuttons.on('click', function() {
            console.log("clicked");
        });
    }

};

NewsNavigator.init({
    displayatonce: 3,
    navbuttons: $('div#nav').find('a')
});
})();
```

Comment: How do you call `enableNav()`? What do you get from `console.log(this.navbuttons);` - maybe `[]`?

Comment: @Niko yes, precisely! I get `[]` in return.

Comment: Looks like the jQuery selector `div#nav a` didn't match any DOM elements, and therefore returned an empty array. You can probably solve this by putting the call to NewsNavigator.init() into a DOM-ready event: `$(function() { NewsNavigator.init(...`

Comment: @Niko which is in my opinion kind of odd, because if I type the exact expression from the console, the two `a` elements are correcly shown.

Comment: @haunted85, it works in console, because when you run this in console, DOM is ready hence it find the elements properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because as you are using `(function())();` which executes the function immediately, maybe it's running the code before the [`dom is ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

everything is working fine in the below demo

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/nCLR5/)

Put all your code inside `document ready` or at least call the `initialize` method inside `doc ready block` like

```
 $(function(){
    NewsNavigator.init({
        displayatonce: 3,
        navbuttons: $('div#nav').find('a')
    });
});
```

Read more about `Javascript self executing Anonymous function` here

[Javascript self executing function "is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090912/javascript-self-executing-function)

or

http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: Apparently I had this wrong idea that `(function())();` was equal to `$(document).ready(function() {})`, when clearly it's not! now it works!!

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery too soon, specifically before the DOM is ready to be searched.

Here is fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/w7KaY/ (JavaScript is placed in `<head>`, so init() is invoked pretty early)  while here (http://jsfiddle.net/w7KaY/1/), the call to init() is encapsulated in an event handler for jQuery's DOM-ready event.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the html elements are there in the DOM. I don't see any issue with the script other than the fact you have to use the `bind` method for binding to events.

```
this.navbuttons.bind('click', function() {
   console.log("clicked");
});
```