# Alternative way to use JavaScript to write to a <div> element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print out a message in the page's `<div>` element upon page load. I have the following HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<body onload="printMsg()">
    <div id="write"></div>
</body>

function printMsg() {
    var node = document.getElementById("write");
    node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Hello World!" + "</p>";
}
```

Here I used `onload` event in `<body>` element to call `printMsg()` upon page load.

But if I don't use `onload` event, is there any alternative way to write to `<div id="write"></div>` directly within the JavaScript function `printMsg()`?

Comment: You can't write to a DOM element until it's loaded so you'd need some kind of callback equivalent to `onload`.  If you want to avoid it you should be able to just make sure the `script` tag comes after the DOM element, I'd suggest right before the end of the `body`.  You are writing to the `div` in the function...you can't invoke a function within it's declaration but you can do so immediately afterward `function() {..}();`.   So try moving `printMsg` down and adding the `();` after the closing brace.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It seems that I cannot put <div onload="printMsg()"></div> to invoke the function printMsg(). So besides the approaches pointed by others, is there any way to invoke the printMsg() function by adding a callback to <div> element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as Whipple suggested you can do it as following :

```
   <body>
    <div id="write"></div>
    <script>
    (function printMsg() {
        var node = document.getElementById("write");
        node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Hello World!" + "</p>";
    })();
    </script>
    </body>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yKEJB/)

Comment: I think you want to remove the `onload`.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili: Thanks a lot. So what is the magic here? Why can we use (function printMsg() {} )() to get rid of onload event?

Comment: @tonga there is no magic here.i just declared a self-calling function.this type of function in javascript called `closure`.check this link for more info about `closure` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090912/javascript-self-executing-function

Comment: Thanks Behnam. I've heard this term in JS before. Will dig into it more :)

Comment: @tonga it is an [immediately invoked function express](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), which creates a closure. (All squares are rectangles; not all rectangles are squares, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can put these function inside the declaration:
    $(document).ready(function() {
    });

You can call these in you header inside 'script', or put it in another file and call it back.
All the functions inside this declaration will run with the loading of the page. The effect is the same that you onload, but don't mess with your body tag.

Comment: Question doesn't mention jQuery so this isn't going to be a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple javascript function to create an element instead of manually writing each tag, which can get confusing if you do it a lot.

Also, as Matt Whipple pointed out:

> make sure the script tag comes after the DOM element

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="write"></div>
    <script>printMsg()</script>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function printMsg() {
    newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.innerHTML = "Hello world!";
    document.getElementById("write").appendChild(newElement);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qrsmq/7/

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
window.onload  =   function() {
    var node = document.getElementById("write");
    node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Hello World!" + "</p>";
}
```

or

```
function printMsg() {
    newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.innerHTML = "Hello world!";
    document.getElementById("write").appendChild(newElement);
}
document.body.onload = printMsg;
```

or

```
function printMsg() {
    newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.innerHTML = "Hello world!";
    document.getElementById("write").appendChild(newElement);
}
window.onload  = printMsg;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also `.ready` function, but requires using jQuery.
If you are already thinking of using jquery for other things this is the way to go. It runs once the DOM is ready.

But the most straight forward option would be to call the function inline, at the end of the `body`:

```
<body>
    <div id="write"></div>
    <script>
        (function(){ 
             //do something with #write
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Like the `ready` function it also only waits for the DOM to be loaded, it ia faster than the `onload` listener and it should be as back compatible with browsers ad javascript is =)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myWeb = new Object(), _m = "model", _v = "view", _c = "controller";

myWeb.model = {

    myEle   : "log",
    myText  : "Hello World!"

}
myWeb.view = {

    doText : function() {
        document.getElementById(myWeb[_m].myEle).innerHTML = myWeb[_m].myText;
    }

}
myWeb.controller = {

    init: function() {
        if (document.readyState == "complete") {
            this.run();
        } else {
            setTimeout(myWeb[_c].init, 11);
        }
    },
    run: function() {
        myWeb[_v].doText();
    }

}
myWeb[_c].init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript plugin mustache JS, you render a template with a JSON notation and javascript. Minimal templating with {{mustaches}} in JavaScript. Allow you to use for a simple or complex template with a minimal code.

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Example of code:

```
// Json Data and Javascript function to calculate the value of return
var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function () {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};

// The HTML Rendered with a simple example of template
var output = Mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);

// Use your New HTML with native Javascript
document.getElementById("divWrite").innerHTML(output);

// Or you use your New HTML with JQuery
$("#divWrite").html(output);
```