# How to refresh div every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, document.write

I have a script which displays a cookie value throw document.write.

How can I refresh the script- update it every 30 seconds?

Or, if it's imposible, to get cookie value again.
        value = GetCookie('VisitorName');

or, put it in iframe and reload the iframe scr.

Code is below:

```
    var expDays = 30;
    var exp = new Date();
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));

    function Who(info) {
        var VisitorName = GetCookie('VisitorName')

        if (VisitorName == null) {
            VisitorName = "Dear visitor";
            SetCookie ('VisitorName', VisitorName, exp);
       }

        return VisitorName;
    }

    function set() { 
        VisitorName = prompt("");
        SetCookie ('VisitorName', VisitorName, exp);
    }

    function getCookieVal (offset) {
        var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);

        if (endstr == -1)
            endstr = document.cookie.length;

       return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
    }

    function GetCookie (name) {
        var arg = name + "=";
        var alen = arg.length;
        var clen = document.cookie.length;
        var i = 0;

        while (i < clen) {
            var j = i + alen;
            if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
        return getCookieVal (j);
            i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
            if (i == 0)
                 break;
        }   

        return null;
   }

    function SetCookie (name, value) {
        var argv = SetCookie.arguments;
        var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;
        var expires = (argc>2) ? argv[2] : null;
        var path = (argc >3) ? argv[3] : null;
        var domain = (argc >4) ? argv[4] : null;
        var secure = (argc >5) ? argv[5] : false;
        document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
            ((expires == null) ? "" : (";expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) +
            ((path == null) ? "" : (";path=" + path)) +
            ((domain == null) ? "" : (";domain=" + domain)) +
            ((secure == true) ? ";secure" : "");
    }

    function DeleteCookie (name) {
        var exp = new Date();
        exp.setTime (exp.getTime() - 1);

        var cval = GetCookie (name);
        document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
    }

    document.write("" + Who() + ",")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` [functions here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval).

```
function myFunc() {
  alert('Hi')
}
setTimeout(myFunc, 30000) // 1000 ms = 1 second
```

So I'm not sure what function you want repeated every 30 seconds but it may look something like this:

```
function MyTimerFunction() {
  document.write("" + Who() + ",")
}
MyTimerFunction(); // runs MyTimerFunction immediately
setInterval(MyTimerFunction, 5000) // run MyTimerFunction it every 5 seconds
```

Comment: It reloads, but showing result on clean page. And it adds the new valuw next to the old, so  I have more one value value value each time interval! I want to stay on the content page and delete the previous value. Maybe I have to insert it in <frame> tags of something like this?

Comment: Frames are rarely the way to go. You'll want to create a div element on the page and have the function write to it. Pretty easy but without the whole html code its hard to explain quickly without knowing your skill level.  Look at the [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119856/alternative-way-to-use-javascript-to-write-to-a-div-element) for how to write to the a div.  This would replace the `document.write("" + Who() + ",")` line.

Comment: I wrote it, again the same result <script>
    (function MyTimerFunction() {
        var node = document.getElementById("write");
        node.innerHTML = ("" + Who() + ",");
      MyTimerFunction(); // runs MyTimerFunction immediately
setInterval(MyTimerFunction, 30000)
        })(); // run MyTimerFunction it every 5 seconds
</script>

Comment: Maybe remove and then re-add the script, like:

$('script').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src') !== 'assets/js/jquery.min.js') {
        var old_src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', '');
        setTimeout(function(){ $(this).attr('src', old_src + '?'+new Date()); }, 250);
    }
});

Comment: Maybe to get streight the cookie value like: document.getElementById('visitor).value = GetCookie('VisitorName');

Comment: Since you've now brought jQuery this will make things easier/cleaner. I never got your entire html so I'm guessing what you are trying to do.That said, I want to point out a few gotcha's. First, working with cookies mean you probably want to test the file online, meaning http:// is in your browser address because most browsers don't do cookies over file:// protocol. Second, make sure your page is fully loaded before javascript tries to access DOM below it. jQuery makes this easy.

Comment: With the gotcha's mentioned above in mind, checkout [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jason-rutherford/3ae6a87d2f6de2865691) for a working sample.